# Appcompat_v7 not created when I create a new project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I did an update of ADT yesterday and since yesterday I can't create new project under Eclipse. My old projects are working fine but the new ones don't work at all. I think the problem is coming from the fact that the file appcompat_v7 is not created when I create a new project and I don't know why this file is not created. I tried several solution like uninstalling ADT and installing ADT several time, check if android build tool and Android support library were installed. I'm running out of solution.
Does anyone had this problem before? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: please add screen shot or other things what have you tried and where is the problem.

Comment: import Appcompat_v7 manually from android-sdk (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7) or check this https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Always do a Help/Check for updates, after updating the SDK

Comment: What I do to automatically make Eclipse add appcompat_v7 is set min SDK to 8 when creating new project, then create a project with Navigation Drawer

Comment: First, thank you all for your replies. I imported the appcompat_v7 manually it's not solving the problem since when I create a new project with the option Blank activity it's not working. I did also checked for updates no new updates. I always set min SDK to 8 when creating a new project and it still not working the file appcompat_v7 is not created.

Comment: it only auto-imports if it is needed, hence why I said Navigation Drawer type navigation certainly auto-imports.

Comment: OK sorry I've tested and it's not working appcompat is not created.

Answer (score 0):

You can import AppCompat_v7 from

"SDK_Location\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7"

Comment: Already done and it's not solving my problem since when I create a new project with the option "blank activity" it's not working.